# How to control the returning array from a method by a way similar to toString()

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, tostring

I have a question about returning an array. I want the array to be ready for printing without using a while loop to print its elements.

I can do this when the array is an instance variable in a class by overriding the .toString(). However, I don't know how to do this when it comes to returning an array. I just used a while loop in the main method to print each element individually. My aim is to do it automatically by using this statement only:

```
System.out.println("Largest stock items: " + shop.largestStockItems(FILTERING_VALUE));
```

and getting a result as this automatically:

```
Largest stock items: 
Code: c03
Name: jug
Price: 8.000
Quantity: 75

Code: c01
Name: mug
Price: 0.900
Quantity: 60
```

So, what are the changes I can do with largestStockItems() or any other method if any??

This is what I am actually having(which I don't want):

main:

```
//display the largest stock items
        System.out.println("Largest stock items: ");
        Item[] largestStockItemsList = shop.largestStockItems(FILTERING_VALUE);
        for (Item item : largestStockItemsList){
            System.out.println(item);
        }
```

largestStockItems() in the Shop class:

```
/**
 * Get the list of largest stock of items
 * @param value the value to which the item is checked
 * @return  the list of largest stock of items
 */
public Item[] largestStockItems(double value){
    Filter[] filtered = Data.filterItems(Arrays.copyOf(items,currentSize), value);
    return Arrays.copyOf(filtered,filtered.length,Item[].class);
}
```

This is the .toString method in the Item class:

```
/**
 * Returns the description of the item
 * @return the description of the item
 */
public String toString() {
    return "Code: " + id
            + "\nName: " + name
            + "\nPrice: " + String.format("%.3f", price)
            + "\nQuantity: " + quantity +"\n";
}
```

Comment: Write a helper method to do it

Comment: There's already a helper method: `Arrays.toString(Object[])`.  But you probably won't like the format it comes out with, so you'll end up writing your own anyway.

Comment: @KevinAnderson how to do it?

Comment: @user7 how do you mean?

Comment: Move the logic to loop and print the contents to a method and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution should work:

```
System.out.println("Largest stock items: " + Arrays.toString(shop.largestStockItems(FILTERING_VALUE)));
```

If you need to print in the format mentioned in the question, try below code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(shop.largestStockItems(FILTERING_VALUE)).map(Item::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n")));
```

Comment: This will print it with the default format with the brackets. I want it to be with the shown format above.

Comment: stream is only way which i could find and which is working successfully. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Noussa Did this work for you?? Did you get any better approach?